# Niche topics (preferably in number theory) that a high school student could find some results in?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, soft-question, contest-math

my teacher recently asked me to come up with a math project to be submitted to a competition, and I have a hard time coming up with ideas. I've recently been solving number theory problems and one concept that caught my attention was Vieta Jumping. I was thinking to generalize the types of expressions usually found in olympiad problems that require Vieta Jumping. I want to find conditions such that expressions like $$ ax^2+by^2+cz^2+dw^2...\over A\cdot xyzw...$$ are integers and when they are, I want to find the values they can take.

Apart from this maybe another interesting topic could be the applications of higher (but not too high) math on high school olympiad problems. If you could give any insights as to what might be a suitable research area I'd very much appreciate it. Thanks.

Note: I can give examples of past projects if it would help put things into perspective.

Comment: Congruences for binomial coefficients (a la Lucas, Babbage, Jacobsthal, Kazandzidis, Wolstenholme, Fine, Ljunggren, etc.), [Somos-like sequences](https://faculty.uml.edu//jpropp/somos.html), and point-counting questions over finite fields (e.g., Jacobsthal sums) are good fields where new results keep getting proved with elementary methods. For instance, I recently wrote [a note on the former](http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/t14/t14.pdf).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Wow, I just took a look at your paper and it seems really interesting! Thank you, and I'll be sure to check out the other topics too.

Comment: http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf

Comment: Re *Other interesting topics*: maybe some [diophantine equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation), notably [Pell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) and [FLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) on small exponents (see also [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent)). [Continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) are also quite fun. [Bézout theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) is simpler but involves both preceding topics.

Comment: Not number theory but in middle school I had the same situation that you did. Graph theory was my solution -- it's easy to understand and problems tend to be solvable by olympiad-style methods. Plus its applicable to the real world more than other topics, which is a major upside if you're entering it into a research/stem fair.